# GDB Doesn't Return Prompt on macOS After Run

Tags: macos, assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'm new to assembly, and am consequently also learning to play around with GDB.

I've got a simple program I'm trying to test GDB with:

```
 global _main

 SECTION .data ;ro = read only
     txt DB 0x41, 0x0A, 0x00 ;db = define byte
     .len EQU $ - txt ;Assembler constant definition: Make len (current memory position start of line ($$ is start of current section) - position of txt)

 SECTION .text ;Code

 _main:
     ;Write message
     MOV rax, 0x02000004 ;sys_write
     MOV rdi, 1 ;File descriptor stdout
     MOV rdx, txt.len ;Message length
     MOV rcx, txt ;Message to write
     SYSCALL ;Return value stored in rax

     ;Exit
     MOV rdi, rax ;Copy return value to rdi as exit code
     MOV rax, 0x02000001 ;Exit syscall number
     SYSCALL
```

After setting breakpoints (e.g. `b 18` -- before the program exits) and running the program via `r`, GDB announces that it is running the program on a new thread and my prompt is indefinitely taken away. `^C` does nothing, and all I can do to stop the process is kill it.

I barely know what I'm doing, so probably something dumb, but how do I get my prompt to return so I can interact with GDB?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `;ro = read only` is just a comment, and is wrong: `.data` is where compilers put non-const non-zero-initialized data like `static char txt[] = {0x41, 10, 0};`.  On Linux, `section .rodata` would be what compilers use for `static const`; not sure of the MacOS section name but you could easily check `clang -S` output for a C program with global-scope `const char ptr[] = ...`. or any string literals.

Comment: Also, explicit-length strings don't need a `0` byte at the end: you're actually outputting that `0` byte to stdout, along with your `"A\n"` string.  GDB and your terminal *shouldn't* crap out because of that, but worth trying removing the `, 0x00` part.